# Tracking groupwise churn

Tags: r, plyr

I have a set of data containing records for student information for an after-school program.  The dataset contains 29 variables, however, I am only using 3 for this problem:

edit: this is already done, the below example is for illustrative purposes

```
student_id  year    group number
1   2009-10 1
2   2009-10 1
3   2009-10 2
4   2009-10 3
5   2009-10 3
1   2010-11 1
2   2010-11 2
3   2010-11 3
4   2010-11 2
5   2010-11 2
1   2011-12 2
3   2011-12 2
4   2011-12 1
```

I would like to track students' progression through the program to see if the drop out before the end of the program.  To do this, I'd like to compute a simple dummy variable that indicates whether or not they attended that year, the result being something like this:

```
student_id  enroll.year1    enroll.year2    enroll.year3
1   1   1   1
2   1   1   0
3   1   1   0
4   1   1   1
5   1   1   0
```

finally, I would like to report it these results aggregated by year and group, like so:

EDIT: these numbers are 100% made up, and are put here completely for illustration purposes

```
Year    Group   retention rate
2009-10 1   0.77
2010-11 1   0.88
2011-12 1   0.8
2009-10 2   0.2
2010-11 2   0.5
2011-12 2   0.6
2009-10 3   0.5
2010-11 3   0.5
2011-12 3   0.5
```

retention rate here would be defined as "#who did not return for that year (value of 0)/total size of group"

I am new to R, but I've been experimenting with ddply to create groupwise summaries and transformations.  I'm stumped on how to get the second step, however.  My attempt at a ddply summary statement is this:

```
tracking=ddply(data,"student_id", transform, enroll.year1=1, enroll.year2=student_id %in% year2 ifelse(TRUE,1,0)
```

however, this is not syntactically correct.  Would appreciate any help with the nuances of implementing this

Comment: For the first part, perhaps, see something like `table(DF$student_id, DF$year)`

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear.  I have the first part subsetted already, it's the middle and last part that's tricky

Comment: I'm not sure what's the formula for the "retention rate", could you clarify it?

Comment: definition added to description

Comment: So in first row of the desired result, you have .77. I still don't understand how did you get this number. Group 1 had two students in 2009. Both attended the next year, except that one of them joined another group. So it should be etiher 0.5 or 100%. Can you explain this?

Comment: Yes.  Those numbers are completely made up, and only there for demonstrating the format of my ideal output :)

Comment: hmmm... That not a good practice at all, because you''d never get an answer if I wouldn't question them. Please fix